# How to load json data in form of map in spark sql?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have json data as shown

```
  "vScore": {
  "300x600": {
    "v1": "0.50",
    "v2": "0.67",
    "v3": "ATF",
    "v4": "H2",
    "v5": "0.11"
  },
  "728x90": {
    "v1": "0.48",
    "v2": "0.57",
    "v3": "Unknown",
    "v4": "H2",
    "v5": "0.51"
  },
  "300x250": {
    "v1": "0.64",
    "v2": "0.77",
    "v3": "ATF",
    "v4": "H2",
    "v5": "0.70"
  },
```

I want to load this json data in the form of map i.e. I want to load vScores in the map so that 300x250 becomes the key and the nested v1...v5 becomes the value of map.
How to do it in spark sql in scala?

Comment: i tried to load json file using read.json() and then tried to use the spark sql query ("SELECT Map(vScores) from df")

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to load your data using

```
data = sqlContext.read.json("file")
```

2. you can check how your data was loaded

```
data.printSchema()
```

3. get your data with "Select" query , using

```
data.select....
```

More:
[How to parse jsonfile with spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168075/how-to-parse-jsonfile-with-)

Comment: But i want to read my data in form of map .....How is it possible by your approach?

Comment: Let assume that you have done the step 3 like :


mydata=select (field1,field2).where(...)
You can transform your data into a map using "foreach" :
myMap = mydata.map(x => (key,value ) )

The key will be something like " x.getString(0)"
The value will be someting like "x.getString(1)"

           Depending in the result of your select query , you may have to split each line of it to get your key and value .

Try to print the result of your Select query to know if you have to split your data or not.

Comment: The question here is to read JSON as a map data structure. Providing a way to read a JSON file is just noise here.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar thing. So, here is a simple way to achieve it.

I'm using Spark Shell here.

Spark always considers a JSON object a struct unless you explicitly provide a schema. So, first, define a schema and read the file.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

scala> val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("vScore", MapType(StringType, MapType(StringType, StringType)))))

scala> val df = spark.read.schema(schema).option("multiLine","true").json("/Users/iraj/Downloads/so.json")

scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- vScore: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Then, I suggest to switch to Dataset by defining a `case class`. It's easier. You can still do the same thing using DataFrame and SQL expressions.

```
scala> import spark.implicits._

scala> case class MyDataModel(vScore: Map[String, Map[String, String]])

scala> val ds = df.as[MyDataModel]
```

Now transform it to what you want.

```
scala> val df2 = ds.map(row => row.vScore.map{ case (resolution, values) => resolution -> values.values.toList}).toDF("vScore")

scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- value: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

 scala> df2.show(truncate = false)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|vScore                                                                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{300x600 -> [0.67, 0.11, 0.50, H2, ATF], 728x90 -> [0.57, 0.51, 0.48, H2, Unknown], 300x250 -> [0.77, 0.70, 0.64, H2, ATF]}|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For the transformation part, I'm unsure if I understood your desired output correctly or not. So, let me know, and I can modify it.